# Breakpoints not triggering when debugging local Firebase functions with emulator with IntelliJ Ultimate/WebStorm

Tags: firebase, debugging, google-cloud-functions, webstorm

I'm running Firebase Tools v9+

I'm running the following start command:

```
firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions
```

And the output:

```
[emulators] >  Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/2eff20bf-d538-42ee-8ed9-067564408152
[emulators] >  Debugger listening on ws://localhost:9229/2eff20bf-d538-42ee-8ed9-067564408152
[emulators] >  For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
[emulators] >  Debugger attached.
```

I created a debugger profile Attach to Node.js/Chrome with my host as localhost and my port as `9229` with attach to set to Chrome or Node.js > 6.3 started with `--inspect`

Unfortunately, the breakpoints are not triggering and I can't step through my functions. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem. I managed to successfully attach IntelliJ debugger to the emulator. But no breakpoints are triggered. I tried chrome dev-tools node inspect tool, too. With this one I managed to trigger breakpoints. But after some short period of time it stops working. In both cases I noticed that cloud functions will start hanging as if they are running into a breakpoint, but the attached debugger does not show.

Comment: Would be worth trying with another editor. I'll try with vscode and report back.

Comment: no luck with vscode either

Comment: Exactly. It seems to attach successfully (the bottom bar even turns orange) but the breakpoints show "unbound breakpoint" tooltip and they're black instead of red  :-/

Comment: BTW, I have successfully debugged cloud functions many times in VS using `firebase functions:shell --inspect-functions`. It's only when running through the emulator that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3):

works for me... I've (more or less) followed the instructions at https://medium.com/firebase-developers/debugging-firebase-functions-in-vs-code-a1caf22db0b2: started the emulator with `firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions`, created the **Attach to Node.js/Chrome** with **Port** set to `9229`, pressed **Debug**, then sent a post request - breakpoint in my function was successfully hit

[image]

Does debugging work for you when using other editors (VSCode, for example)?

Comment: I'll try with vscode today and get back to you!

Comment: Yeah, haven't been able to get it working with vscode either.

Comment: I had to update `firebase-tools` for this to work in VS Code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Even though the breakpoint is seemingly unbound, it could hit the line when I execute the corresponding Firebase function.

So, please try to call the function even though the breakpoint is unbound. The breakpoint may be activated and turn to be red in that case.